# Path to images not working in my Angular 4 file

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am a beginner in learning  angular 4 framework and  have seen all the threads regarding this problem on stackoverflow but the solutions given in them not able to solve my problem.

I am getting this error "**http://localhost:4200/src/assets/images/1.jpg 404 (Not Found)**" .All other things are working fine but only image is not getting loaded.
I am giving my .angular-cli.json code and my custom made component code where i given my img tag.

**My custom component code:-**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector:'my-comp',
    template:`<button (mousemove)="clicked($event)">{{name1}}</button>
                <div *ngIf="applyDiv==false">WTF</div>
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="let i of a;let j=index">{{j}}.{{i}}</li>
                </ul>    

                <img src="../../src/assets/images/1.jpg" alt="Ms dhoni" width="2000" height="2000"/>
                <input type="text" name="Sahil" value="sahil"/>
                <div [class.myClass]="myclass">Apply Class</div>
                <div [style.color]="applyBlue?'blue':'yellow'">Starting Angualr</div>`,
    styleUrls:['./hello.component.css']


})

export class HelloComponent {
    name='Angular1';
    myclass=true;
    applyBlue=true;
    name1=0;
    applyDiv=false;
    a=[1,'2','3iituit'];
    clicked(event){
        console.log(event.target);
        this.name1++;
    }
   // name1:string="sahil";
    //logo="../../assets/images/mov2.jpg";
}
```

**My code .angular-cli.json:-**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "my-app"

  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [

        "assets/images",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem here.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Path should not contain `src`, `src` folder is the root of your app. `http://localhost:4200/assets/images/1.jpg`

Comment: @Ploppy,I have also tried using that but this is also  not working

Comment: Did you solve this case?

Answer (score 9):

You are supposed to put images in the assets folder that is inside src folder then you can specify path as `assets/../image.png`

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `HelloComponent` is inside the `"src > app"` folder, the following tag should display the image:

```
<img src="../../assets/images/1.jpg" 
          alt="Ms dhoni" 
          width="2000" height="2000"/>
```

If it still doesn't show, then if you are using an IDE fir development, drag the image from the assets folder and drop it in one of the `.html` file inside tge app folder. Check the image src path there.

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the dimensions of the image in paint. I had an image in the path src/assets/Library/Images with dimensions 60 x 45 which did not load and an image with dimensions 225 x 225 which loaded successfully. Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<img [src]="../../src/assets/images/1.jpg" alt="Ms dhoni" width="2000" height="2000"/>
```

Comment: i have simply using <img src> tag ,i am not  doing any property binding .

Comment: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token . at column 1 in [../../assets/images/1.jpg] in ng:///AppModule/HelloComponent.html@6:21 ("
                </ul>    

                <img [ERROR ->][src]="../../assets/images/1.jpg" alt="Ms dhoni" width="2000" height="2000"/>
                <input "): ng:///AppModule/HelloComponent.html@6:21

Comment: try <img [src]="../../src/assets/images/1.jpg" alt="Ms dhoni" width="2000" height="2000">

Comment: try <img [src]="../../src/assets/images/1.jpg" alt="Ms dhoni" width="2000" height="2000">is this not the samething you have posted above

Comment: without the / tag

Comment: This is not working,nothing happens with that .This is shorthand notation for closing the tag in html

Comment: Strange I know that, probably you are referring to the wrong path

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
   <img src="assets/images/1.jpg" alt="Ms dhoni" width="200px" height="200px"/>
```

and make sure you have `<base href="/">` in the index.html `<head>` tag

Comment: ,I have tried this,this is giving following error:"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: http://localhost:4200/assets/images/1.jpg this error is coming ihave tried all this by seeing threads given regarding this same problem on stack overflow

Comment: Ok, one more thing, what is your baseUrl and have you     <base href="/">
in index.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the /dest folder (or whatever you've configured as the output of your webpack) where the app is being served. Do you see any path corresponding to the path being requested? If not then, obviously, the browser isn't gonna be able to load it.

This is because Webpack (or whatever packager you are using) does not have any way of knowing what assets to include in the final deployment of your application unless you tell it - so the files aren't there. Therefore, you can either configure Webpack with a file loader (or url-loader) to output your images to a path at the destination folder structure or you can set properties on your component to the return value of the require('my image url here') function, e.g. this.myIcon=require('images/abc.png'). Use these propertiesto do an attribute binding on your IMG tag like

```html
<img [attr.src]="myIcon" />
```

This will result in the bytes of the image being directly embedded into the src attribute via a data: url (inspect the final element in Chrome to see). (This last part I may not have exactly right but something definitely translates the images into base64-encoded data for your IMG src's to make them appear w/o being present in the destination folder.)

IMHO, this is a big shortcoming with something like the Angular 2 approach with Webpack. You have to configure so much crap just to produce a usable application that it may eventually make you reconsider the entire platform. The better you learn this part of the whole Angular 2 delivery process up front, the happier you will be. Here's a link to an article that may help: https://medium.com/a-beginners-guide-for-webpack-2/copy-all-images-files-to-a-folder-using-copy-webpack-plugin-7c8cf2de7676

Answer (score 0):

Change your folder path
**From**

> E:\Data\project - 1\Angular(learning)\app

**To**

> E:\Data\project1\Angular(learning)\app

Answer (score 0):

the only solution is to convert all images into base64. and copy link and paste it in img src="".